# Select most frequent value in group

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can you help find the solution to select only most frequent value of column "Count" in code:

```
SELECT gl.name as "Client", fvl.value as "Group", m.name as "Line", (1-((s.price/s.price_msrp))) as `Discount`, COUNT(1-((s.price/s.price_msrp))) as "Count" FROM `ps_b2b_customer_specific_price`  as s
JOIN ps_b2b_product as p
on s.id_product = p.id_product
join ps_b2b_product_lang as pl
on p.id_product = pl.id_product and pl.id_lang = 1
join ps_b2b_group_lang as gl
on s.id_group = gl.id_group and gl.id_lang = 1
LEFT join ps_b2b_feature_product as fp
on s.id_product = fp.id_product and fp.id_feature = 649
LEFT join ps_b2b_feature_value_lang as fvl
on fp.id_feature_value = fvl.id_feature_value and fvl.id_lang = 1
LEFT join ps_b2b_cennik as cennik
on s.id_product = cennik.id_product
LEFT join ps_b2b_manufacturer as m
on m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer
LEFT join ps_b2b_category_lang as cl
on cl.id_category = cennik.kategoria_root and cl.id_lang = 1
WHERE MOD((1-((s.price/s.price_msrp)))*1000,1) = 0
GROUP BY `Client`, `Group`, `Line`, `Discount`  
ORDER BY `Client` ASC
```

In this why i have result like:

```
ClientX | A | L | 0.5500000000 | 54
ClientX | A | L | 0.6200000000 | 1
ClientX | A | P | 0.5500000000 | 18
ClientX | A | U | 0.5500000000 | 11
```

And in this case second row is wrong cause the most frequent value for "Discount" is 0.55. How to selected rows only with maximum count value for all groups?

Thanks for answear  :)

Comment: You can COUNT() values in a subquery, get result in descending ORDER and LIMIT it. Then use this subquery result inside WHERE statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you need; can you state your desired output?

Comment: But if you only want the one line with maximum Count, do as Darkitechtor advised: ORDER BY Count DESC then LIMIT 1.

Comment: ClientX | A | L | 0.5500000000 | 54


ClientX | A | P | 0.5500000000 | 18

ClientX | A | U | 0.5500000000 | 11

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this subquery with connected to this select

Comment: Is it possible at all? Or only when the results are saved in the newly created table?